# Inability to increase the quota due to an error in the application form

Tags: youtube-data-api

In our application, we use the YouTube API to let the user sing their
favorite songs. But as soon as we added the YouTube API to the app in Build
Number 6.01, we immediately exceeded the quota of queries. But when filling
out the quota increase request form, we are faced with the fact that the
application page https://services.google.com/fb/forms/ytapiquotarequest/
uses reCaptcha V1, which is not supported since April 2018. As a result, we
can not request an increase in the quota. Can you aassist in extending the
quota limit for daily YouTube API requests?

Comment: This should be a YouTube support request.  StackOverflow is not a support channel for YouTube.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.